# why drop row got error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'No'

Tags: pandas, csv, attributeerror

Hi I am trying to drop a row from a Data frame, loaded from a CSV file:

```
no_show_raw_data = pd.read_csv("noshowappointments.csv")

df = no_show_raw_data

new_df = df[df.No-show != 'No']
```

but i get this error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'No'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns **No-show** has a minus sign in the name, try brackets instead:

```
no_show_raw_data = pd.read_csv("noshowappointments.csv")

df = no_show_raw_data

new_df = df[df['No-show'] != 'No']
```

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark this question as solved, so it's no longer open.